# How perform Some task In Background in iOS

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios6

I want perform some database related task in background for that I have added code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             0), ^(void) {
        [lclDB  deleteRecoredwithBlock:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"Deletion Succesful...");
            }
        }];
    });
```

deleteRecord function internally calls number of methods sequentially to perform delete operation in local database.now I have wait until all delete operation is performed.but I want to do this whole delete operation in background.if any one known please help me to figure out these problem.

Comment: You call is right. You are starting the `dispatch_async` block. While it is deleting the records asynchronously, you can continue doing other  things.

Comment: Just put a `NSLog` after this code. It will be printed before "Deletio Succesful..."

Answer (score 1):

Any NSObject can perform action in background using the following :

```
[myObject performSelectorInBackground:@selector(anAction) withObject:nil];
```

[More information on apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundMethod) withObject:nil];
```

You can also use [NSInvocationOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(deleteDataWithOperation) object:nil];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

And this is your `deleteDataWithOperation` method -

```
-(void)deleteDataWithOperation
{
   //Do your work here
}
```